# Update all changed tables in SAP BODS datastore

Tags: hana, sap-data-services

In order to transform and load data I am only able to connect to data stores that have already been imported into Data Services from HANA. In my case the tables might change in the forthcoming future so I wanted to script the transform through SQL.

Is there a way I can connect to HANA directly instead of going through each individual datastore (which have to be created with individual tables)?

I have used SSIS earlier and I know I can connect and write SQL queries to pull data from multiple tables directly only if I have connection to the database. I was expecting something similar in Data Services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have used SSIS earlier and I know I can connect and write SQL queries to pull data from multiple tables directly only if I have connection to the database

Of course, SAP Data Services allows the same. You can import single tables from database, several or the whole database into datastore. For importing all the tables double-click on `Tables` in the datastore, in the right panel all the tables of the HANA table will be showed, then you just right-click and select `Import`.

[image]

After your schema changes, you just go the same process and click `Reconcile` as on screenshot.

More about reconciliation process is here: [Determining if a schema has changed since it was imported](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/4.2.11/en-US/5728b6c76d6d1014b3fc9283b0e91070.html)

If only single table has changed, you can make re-import selectively [Reimporting objects](https://help.sap.com/viewer/ec06fadc50b64b6184f835e4f0e1f52f/4.2.9/en-US/57231ea06d6d1014b3fc9283b0e91070.html)

> through each individual datastore (which have to be created with individual tables)?

no, once you created datastore specifying valid schema, you can import/reconcile all the tables of this schema at once.

Also, consider [this al_engine utility](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_DATA_SERVICES/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/5717941e6d6d1014b3fc9283b0e91070.html) which you can use in scripts to automate imports.

More documentation about SAP HANA specifics in Data Services:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/e54136ab6a4a43e6a370265bf0a2d744/4.2.14/en-US/d27bb7d0ac4c456e8f035d6bbc81081a.html

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try this next time!